# Confidence Interval for Proportions

Tags: probability, statistics

According the formula 
$\bar p \pm \sqrt{\frac{\bar p (1 - \bar p)}{n}}Z\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$ 
In some extreme case for example Observed Proportion = $99\%$, Sample Size = $100$ and Desired Confidence level is $99\%$. The Range for the true population proportion will be: $96.44\%$ to $101.56\%$ , one side is $>1$. Or it may be $<0$ when the Observed Proportion is extremely small.
My question is: Is the number mean anything when it's $>1$ or $<0$ ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please, use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for the comment and I fixed it.